# Multiple rewrite conditions for multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

There is an issue with the htaccess rewrite conditions in my setup.

Currently I have the following code.

> ```
>    Options +FollowSymLinks 
>    RewriteEngine on 
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydom.com/$1.php
> ```

This works fine for any base page making them look like this.

> ```
>    http://mydom.com/page
> ```

What I want to also be able to do is add parameters from the url if they exist.  I have some pages that will be like this.

> ```
>   http://mydom.com/page?param=1&secondParam=2
> ```

What I've tried to do is add this.

> ```
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://mydom/$1/$2/$3 [L]
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://mydom/$1/$2 [L]
> ```

This made sense to me, because I thought if the condition didn't match, it would move on, but this gave me an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was setting up a separate rule for each page that could have multiple parameters like this.

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ http://mydom.com/page.php?param=$1&secondParam=$2 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ http://mydom.com/page.php?param=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydom.com/$1.php

This works, however you need to keep in mind relative links you may have in your site such as style sheets and javascript files.  In my case, I had to replace all relative paths with full site paths, depending on the way you set up your site, it could take a while to replace.